# Options to Recess Google Home Within Wall

Tags: electrical, drywall, home-automation

I would love to embed a Google Home Max within my wall as seen in the attached picture.  Looking for some guidance on how to tie it into a power source which is a switch like shown in the picture.  I would like the solution to keep the screen pretty flush with the wall.

Appreciate any advice or products that would work.

Thanks!
Cliff

[image]

Comment: There is no switch in the photo. Would you really want it on switch that can be turned off and on? To recess it you will need to cut open the wall and frame in a niche, run power in the wall to the niche, install outlet, and then drywall and mud/tape/paint.  Are you capable of all of that.

Comment: Sorry.  The swtich got cut out of the picture.  I wouldn't want it on a switch, but would want to just tie into the power that feeds the switch.  I am capable of all of the actual work.  What I am struggling with is the right method to tie into the power that is feeding the switch.  The google device has a standard plug and I believe that building code does not allow a plug to be inside the wall.  Mainly looking for a solution around that piece.

Comment: You will not have room in the wall for an outlet box on the back of the niche ( in a 2x4 wall ) or on the side of the niche because it is so shallow, so i would get one of those flat panel tv in wall wiring kits, it has a port for the back of the  niche for the wires to run in the wall and out at an out in the wall just below the ("tv") niche. ( Choosing a location over an existing outlet is going to be much easier and cheaper then opening your wall to tie into a switch and run power through studs to a new box.

Comment: it very well might not be legal to power it from a switch. you're not supposed to use common AC/DC adapters in-wall for example, you need to get one rated to be used as such. I would run a wire down (out of site) and out, which then connects to a wall wort.

Comment: A recessed niche would be totally legal + Alaska man! I have wired hundreds of up to 4 recessed duplex outlets behind flat screens with both data outlets and power. They only require a divider to be in the same box.

Comment: @EdBeal Yes understood, as have I.  It  is just that the recess is so shallow there is no room on the side of it and because it is a recess there is not enough space from the back of the niche and the other side of the wall. Perhaps a shallow box would work but that would be contingent on the actual space left after the niche is installed. *It is question of having room for the box*.

Comment: Some are deep enough for a wall wart to be flush with the wall. I think 1-1/4” x3 they are spendy and require 6” walls if insulation is required but they will fit in a 2x4 stud bay (tight fit) the hole is larger also, I will try and find them it’s been ~12+ years and they were close to 80$  but that one had 4 ea 120 receptacles 3 coax and 4 cat 5 blocks.

Comment: Yes but the op wants a niche just deep enough for a tablet that is only a 1/2 inch thick at most and he wants it to be flush with the wall. Sticking with those requirements makes it TRICKY.   That is not a very deep niche but it may be deep enough to negate the use of a full size electrical box on its back side. ( if it is a 2x4 wall )

Comment: can you make a niche 3.5" deep and mount the box recessed into the side of the wall or is that considered concealed? Kind of like an access hatch. Then just install a mounting bracket inside the niche for the google home

Answer (score 1):

They make [recessed junction boxes](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Eaton-15-Amp-125-Volt-5-15R-Single-Recessed-Receptacle-with-Clock-Hanger-White-TR775W-BOX-SP/206469310) specifically for fitting receptacles where a "wall wart" will be plugging into them.

If there is not space to mount one in the recess flush, then you can build the recess deeper in the middle, and side-mount the junction box.